# In a specific row of a table replace a "*" with a checked checkbox, and "" with a checkbox that is not checked

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a couple of tables and want to replace column 2 or column 5 (if it exists) with check boxes.

If there is an asterisk in the cell, I want the check box checked = True.

If there's no asterisk, the cell will only be a unchecked check box. These check boxes are from the developer tab, under controls, legacy forms.

I researched but failed:

- replacing an asterisk with a check box (checked)
- limiting it to a specific column (see image)
- replacing a blank cell with a check box (unchecked)
- limiting the action to a specific column (2 and 5 (if it exists))

```vb
Dim oCell As Cell
Dim oRow As Row

For Each oRow In Selection.Tables(1).Rows
    For Each oCell In oRow.Cells 'this won't work specifically with my example, needs to be a little more specific
        If oCell.Range.Text = "*" Then
            MsgBox oCell.RowIndex & ", " & oCell.ColumnIndex & " check it!"
            'I don't how to put in a check box here
        End If
    Next oCell
Next oRow

'I want to combine the top code and code below...right?
'do for each cell in column 2
With ActiveDocument.FormFields.Add(Range:=ActiveDocument.Selection, Type:=wdFieldFormCheckBox)
    If cellvalue = "" Then 'just verbal logic here
        .CheckBox.Value = False
    End If
    If cellvalue = "*" Then 'just verbal logic here
        .checkbox.Value = True
    End If
End With
```

[image: Image of document]

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do this:

```
Dim objDoc As Document
Dim oCell As Cell
Dim oCol As Column
Dim objTable As Table
Dim bFlag As Boolean

Set objDoc = ActiveDocument
Set objTable = Selection.Tables(1)

'This may or may not be necessary, but I think it's a good idea. 
'Tables with spans can not be accessed via the spanned object.
'Helper function below.
If IsColumnAccessible(objTable, 2) Then
    For Each oCell In objTable.Columns(2).Cells
        'This is the easiest way to check for an asterisk, 
        'but it assumes you have decent control over your
        'content. This checks for an asterisk anywhere in the
        'cell. If you need to be more specific, keep in mind
        'that the cell will contain a paragraph return as well,
        'at a minimum.
        bFlag = (InStr(oCell.Range.Text, "*") > 0)
        'Delete the content of the cell; again, this assumes 
        'the only options are blank or asterisk.
        oCell.Range.Delete
        objDoc.FormFields.Add Range:=oCell.Range, Type:=wdFieldFormCheckBox
        'Set the value. I found some weird results doing this 
        'any other way (such as setting the form field to a variable).
        'This worked, though.
        If bFlag Then
            oCell.Range.FormFields(1).CheckBox.Value = True
        End If
    Next oCell
End If
'Then do the same for column 5.



Public Function IsColumnAccessible(ByRef objTable As Table, iColumn As Integer) As Boolean
Dim objCol As Column
'This is a little helper function that returns false if 
'the column can't be accessed. If you know you won't have
'any spans, you can probably skip this.
On Error GoTo IsNotAccessible
IsColumnAccessible = True
Set objCol = objTable.Columns(iColumn)
Exit Function

IsNotAccessible:
IsColumnAccessible = False

End Function
```